# Handling CR line endings in Lua

Tags: file, lua, line-endings

I'm trying to read a file with `CR` line endings using the `file:read` method which seems to be acting up for some reason. The file contents look like this:

```
ABCDEFGH
12345
##
6789
```

I want it to behave consistently with all types of line endings. Every time I try to read the file, it returns the last line in the file concatenated with the any trailing characters from the previous lines that have a greater position than the position of the last character in the last line. Here's what I mean:

```
> file=io.open("test.lua", "rb")
> function re_read(openFile)
     openFile:seek("set");
     return openFile:read("*a");
  end
> =re_read(file) -- With CR
67895FGH

> =re_read(file) -- With CRLF
ABCDEFGH
12345
##
6789

> =re_read(file) -- with LF
ABCDEFGH
12345
##
6789

>
```

As you can see, the string being returned is the last string plus `5` in the previous line and plus `FGH` from the first line. Any lines shorter than the last line are skipped.

My goal is to use the `file:line()` method to read the file line by line. My hope is that if a 'fix' for `file:read` is found then it can be applied to `file:lines()`.

Comment: Try opening the file in text mode: change `rb` to `r`.

Comment: it still gives me the same results. The function isn't the problem, it's the REPL(see catwell's answer).

Comment: sorry, it's not the repl either, but rather my understanding of the carriage return character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case with CR only, `re_read` actually works as expected: it returns the lines separated by CR. But when the interpreter displays it, it interprets the CR characters as "go back to the beginning of the line". So here is how the result changes line by line:

```
ABCDEFGH
12345FGH
##345FGH
67895FGH
```

EDIT: here it is character by character, with a "virtual cursor" (`|`).

```
|
A|
AB|
ABC|
ABCD|
ABCDEF|
ABCDEFGH|
|ABCDEFGH
1|BCDEFGH
12|CDEFGH
123|DEFGH
1234|EFGH
12345|FGH
|12345FGH
#|2345FGH
##|345FGH
|##345FGH
6|#345FGH
67|345FGH
678|45FGH
6789|5FGH
```

Proof:

```
> s = "ABCDEFGH\r12345\r##\r6789"
> =s
67895FGH
```

Comment: putting it in a string makes it even more confusing. If it starts from `'A'` moving towards `'9'` in the string, won't it be stuck in a non ending loop if, as you say, CR returns it to the beginning of the line?

Comment: I don't understand your "non ending loop" problem. It reads the string from left to right and goes back to the beginning of the line exactly three times (the number of `\r` characters in the string). To be clear: it goes back to the beginning of the line in the *output*, not in the string it is displaying.

Comment: I had edited my answer and added a "character by character example", maybe it will make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could normalize your line endings with `gsub` then iterate over the product with `gmatch`.

```
local function cr_lines(s)
    return s:gsub('\r\n?', '\n'):gmatch('(.-)\n')
end

local function cr_file_lines(filename)
    local f = io.open(filename, 'rb')
    local s = f:read('*a')
    f:close()
    return cr_lines(s)
end

for ln in cr_file_lines('test.txt') do
    print(ln)
end
```